# replaceAllMapped matches with span elements

Tags: regex, replace, dart, replaceall

I want to replace all matched strings after regExp with same strings in span elements. Is this possible?
I want to do something like that: 
`final text = message.replaceAllMapped(exp, (match) => '<span>exp, (match)</span>');`

Comment: It doesn't work. The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Match) → String'.

Comment: `final exp = new RegExp(r'\d+\.+?\d+');

    String a = 'test 40.40 test 20.20';
    
    final matches = exp.allMatches(a);

    final text = message.replaceAllMapped(exp, '<span>$&</span>');`

I matched 40.40 and 20.20 and i want to make them in span element.

Comment: `final text = message.replaceAllMapped(exp, '<span>$&</span>');` Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`String#replaceAllMapped`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/replaceAllMapped.html) like this:

```
final exp = new RegExp(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?'); 
String message = 'test 40.40 test 20.20'; 
final text = message.replaceAllMapped(exp, 
        (Match m) => "<span>${m[0]}</span>");
print(text);
```

Output: `test <span>40.40</span> test <span>20.20</span>`

Here, `m` is the `Match` object that the regex engine finds and passes to the arrow method where the first item in the `m` array is inserted in between `<span>` and `</span>` inside an interpolated double quoted string literal.

Comment: In browser I want output to be the same (test 40.40 test 20.20), but both numbers should be in span elements. In inspect elements I want `test <span>40.40</span> test <span>20.20</span>`;

Comment: @vesselinivanov That is what you get with the code above. `test <span>40.40</span> test <span>20.20</span>` is what console shows.